# About nextjs minified error after i upgraded to latest versions

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, package, version

currently i am working in my nextjs application and i have update to latest versions of next,reactjs and npm but after making build in my project suddenly i got minified react errors.

This are errors i am getting,

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418;
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9TnY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5z8m.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error can refer to any sort of error.
I've faced a similar error (#418 #423 #425) and found out that I was using `Date` object directly in JSX of a component.

I wrote a helper function to get the date and passed-on date string to that function that in turn returns age, etc. depending on your use case!

This was the helper function I used (just for reference):

```
export const getAge = (dob: Date | string) => {
    let time = typeof dob === 'string' ? new Date(dob).getTime() : dob.getTime()
    let ageDate = new Date(Date.now() - time)
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970)
}
```

I wanted to get the age from a `Date` object, which I managed to achieve by passing Date as a string and then creating Date from that string!

Comment: I don't have the Date object used in my project at all in my project and yet this weird error is there